# Synchronous architecture with asynchronous repository

Tags: javascript, architecture, node.js

In order to keep clean architecture of my node.js microservice I have controllers, services and e.g. repositories.

I want a synchronous data flow: controller -> service -> repository -> service -> controller. In this flow (in simple user story) repository returns data to service and service to controller. But repository should process requests to external storage in a asynchronous way. All asynchronous code should exist only in repository, service should obtain raw data.

My current implementation:

UserController.js

```
module.exports.create = function() {
    console.log("In controller: before service call");

    let userDto = JSON.parse(this.request.body);
    let savedUser = userService.createUser(userDto);

    console.log("In controller: after service call");
};
```

UserService.js

```
module.exports.createUser = function createUser(userDto) {

    let user = require('../domain/user/User');

    user.login = userDto.login;
    user.password = userDto.password;

    let userRepository = require('../infrastructure/user/UserRepository');

    Q.spawn(function* () {
        console.log("In service before promise resolve");

        let savedUser = yield userRepository.createUser(user);

        console.log("In service after promise resolve");

        return savedUser;
    });

    console.log("In service: after repository call");
};
```

UserRepository.js

```
module.exports.createUser = function createUser(user) {
    console.log("In repository: before save call");

    return new Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        userEntity.save(function(err, savedUser) {

            console.log("In repository: inside callback after save call");

            if (err) {
                console.log("In repository: inside callback before reject");
                reject(Error('Błąd zapisu danych!'));
            } else {
                console.log("In repository: inside callback before resolve");
                resolve(savedUser);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Logs:

- In controller: before service call
- In service before promise resolve
- In repository: before save call
- In service: after repository call
- In controller: after service call
- In repository: inside callback after save call
- In repository: inside callback before resolve
- In service after promise resolve

I would like to get the following sequence of logs:

- In controller: before service call
- In service before promise resolve
- In repository: before save call
- In repository: inside callback after save call
- In repository: inside callback before resolve
- In service after promise resolve
- In controller: after service call

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you appear to be asking "How can I call an asynchronous function in a synchronous manner?" to which the answer is "You can't, that's what asynchronous means".

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer having little to no technical knowledge on the capabilities of Node.js as a server architecture.  I am purely speaking to the high level design in a technology agnostic way.

What you are wishing to create is essentially a Synchronous-over-Asynchronous interface.  This is essentially where you provide a service to a client that promises on a given request, that they have a reasonable expectation of receiving a response from the server in X amount of time.  The Alternate expression of this use case is that no response is received in X amount of time and thus a timeout event occurs.

The Repository wraps an asynchronous interface of some kind that makes no guarantee of when you could receive a response. It could respond back in sub-millisecond or in 8 hours.

The disconnect is that your microservice is essentially making a promise to its client that it can't guarantee.  This is a fundamental flaw in the Sync-over-Async model but not an insurmountable one necessarily.

Essentially you first have to guarantee the order of execution of running processes such that you effectively wait on the Asynchronous interface to return a response and finish executing its callback before you leave the Repository.  If you don't do this then you will experience a racing condition like the example you described in your email.

Typically an application server will spawn a thread of execution for each incoming request to process.  The thread ends when a response has been formulated and sent (again, not sure if this is the same in Node.js).  What you need to do is halt the request thread until the callback has finished execution.

Secondly, when you halt the thread, you need to do so until a prescribed timeout has been reached.  In this way if you timeout waiting for the async process to return, you avoid the thread getting stuck and the server hanging.  You can then return a proper exception fault over your service to the client so that they can take action on it.